# WordPress check if query is for a custom type in pre_get_posts filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify a custom post type query using the `pre_get_posts` filter:

```
function custom_query( $query ) {

   $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'a_tax_name',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'a-slug-name'
        )
    );
    $query->set('tax_query', $meta_query);

    return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_query');
```

It works but the query is also applied to all the queries on my page (menu items, sidebar, footer, etc). I only want it to modify the custom post type query. I tried adding in the function:

```
if( $query->is_main_query() ) {
  return;
}
```

or

```
if ( 'my_custom_post_type' !== get_post_type() ) {
   return;
}
```

but not working. How can i use the `pre_get_posts` filter only on a custom post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$query->get('post_type')` to retrieve a post type from the query variables and use it in condition for example.